# Issue with CSS implemented using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have create a jquery to convert `title` attribute of input to span with class `"field_title"`. when I click on input though span class hide but input field remains disabled. Issue is I can't enable the input field.

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" name="email" class="w_def_text" title="Email*" />
  <img class="error" width="27" height="27" src="images/error.jpg" alt="Error"> 
</div>

<script>
function init_fields() {    
    $('.w_def_text').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).attr('title');
        var html = '<span class="field_title">' + text + '</span>';
        $(this).parent().append(html);

        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next().show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({'display' : 'block'});
            $(this).next().hide();
        }
    });

    $('.w_def_text').live('blur', function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next().show();
        }
    });

    $('.w_def_text ~ span').live('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev().css({'display' : 'block'}).focus();
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the issue is, but I think it might be solved to an extent by using label tags instead of spans for the title. More semantic as well, makes sense without a style. Also have the added benefit of setting focus on the associated input field when clicked.

Comment: Too difficult to decipher what you are wanting. Can you give us more to work with or use this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/VwPM2/) to help us a bit more.

Comment: @ swatkins  : Exactly when I click on Email* that is span I want input field here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.w_def_text ~ span').live('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().prev().css({
        'display': 'block'
    }).focus();
});
```

You need `.prev().prev()` because that's the input. And in second function

```
$('.w_def_text').live('blur', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().next().show();
    }
});
```

you need `.next().next()` or something like that depending on what you want. You should understand what is wrong now. :)

Comment: I want bit modification. on blur if input is empty than class="error" should be visible. otherwise on load it should be hidden.

Comment: I did it. Thanks mate. I can't make your reputation +100 otherwise I did it for sure.... :)

Comment: No problem. By the way: have you considered using `placeholder` attribute in `input`? Note that this is HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of:

```
$(this).parent().append(html);
```

you want to do:

```
$(this).after(html);
```

And perhaps be more explicit, instead of just `.next().show()` - specify the sibling class you want to target:

```
$(this).next('.error').show()
...
$(this).next('.error').hide()
```

Comment: Great I got result wat I want but still on blur my error class is not shown if field is null.

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand the requirement, but perhaps using `$(this).next('.error').show()` and `$(this).next('.error').hide()` will get the result you want?